# Android in Eclipse autocompletes arg0, arg1,

Tags: java, android

Come on, I know this is simple, but I can't find an answer.  When I autocomplete in Android in Eclipse, the methods get param names like arg0, arg1, etc.  Presumably, this would be better if I had source or something for Android located somewhere, but there are 14,000 git repositories for it and I don't know which to grab or what to do after.

Can someone help??  I don't want "View arg0" I want "View v" or something. :-)

Comment: @Falmarri: What's wrong with the question?

Comment: This question is so legit, I googled it 2.5 years later and realized it was mine. If you find it satisfactory that autocompleted code shows arg0, I'd hate to know what your code looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that adding the Android source will solve this problem for you.  There are two options, you can follow the instructions to [download the source](http://source.android.com/source/download.html), or alternatively, you can download a jar file from someone who has done the work for you.  This [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=979) has links to various versions of the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Eclipse plugin created by some google devs (iiuc) on google code. Just use [this](http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/) update site in Eclipse and it will provide an android sources to all of your projects.

Slightly more info is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/) (search this page for "Android Source")